# Nintex Form Still Referencing Nintex Live After Uninstalling

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-on-prem, nintex

We have recently uninstalled Nintex Live from our SharePoint 2010 environment but when publishing forms, it errors with reference to missing Nintex Live assembly. This is now preventing us from publishing forms in our live environment.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Nintex.Live.SharePoint Version=1.0.0.0' or one of it's dependencies.
```

Does anyone know if we need to specifically remove all references from the databases and if so, how do we do this? When we uninstalled we followed the documentation [here](https://community.nintex.com/t5/How-To-s/Uninstalling-Nintex-Live-Framework/ta-p/86989)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Recycle application pool.
2. check for dll in wwwroot folder